# Generating random activation code in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I  have a function of activation code

```
function active($activationcode)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE activationcode = '$activationcode';";
    $obj_db = new DB();
    $obj_db->query($sql);
    $row = $obj_db->rsset();
    $id = $row[id];
    $obj_db->db_close();
    return $id; 
}
```

now i am calling itin another page...all i want to do is to generate random number and send the link to the user via e mail.
my function is correct . now i want this code to work . plz help me

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) == "Update")
{
    $userActive = $Users->active($Users->_activationcode());
    $Users->active($_GET['id']);
    $_POST['activationcode'];
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing? 
and how you are calling the function `active`?
Please post the complete code.

Comment: i want this code to get activation code from database

Comment: 1. Please check if the function `active` is getting called.
2. If called just print the query or query result and check.
am not sure about the way you called your function `$Users->active($Users->_activationcode());
`

Comment: yes ..please tell me that am i calling the function rite..? i am just a bigner

Comment: I guess you have a class called `Users` and in that case
It is enough to call just `$this->active($activationcode);`

Comment: @FahadImtiaz .Net mein aja idher chill scene hai tujhe main sab sikha doon ga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) == "Update")
```

To:

```
if($_GET['action'] == "Update")
```

Or better:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "Update")
```

You were comparing the result of `isset()` (boolean) with string `update` which would never become `true`.

Comment: @FahadImtiaz: Is your function `active` inside a class or stand alone ?. Also since you say that you are calling that in another page, are you including the file which contains that function ?

Comment: my funcation name is active and i am also including it

Comment: @FahadImtiaz: My first question was is that function inside a `class` or standalone ? The better you explain your question, the accurate answers you will get here :)

Comment: @FahadImtiaz: Currently what problem is happening exactly, any error message or something ?

Comment: @FahadImtiaz: Well then it is not easy to say with provided information. You will have to check whetehr `$activationcode` is really being passed to function because we dont know what your functions are doing such as `$row = $obj_db->rsset();`, `$Users->_activationcode()`. If `_activationcode` is not a function but a variable, you will have to use `$userActive = $Users->active($Users->_activationcode);` instead of `$userActive = $Users->active($Users->_activationcode());`. Stripped ending `()` from that.

Comment: @FahadImtiaz: Also whether your function is `static` or has other visibility in which case `::` will be used instead of `->`. So as I said, you need to provide full context and code to get accurate answer.